# Force R to evaluate string as column name

Tags: r, evaluation

I have a script that allows the user to choose a column to process by inputting a column name prefix at the console. The first example below shows a typical operation: counting the number of occurrences of a score. The input table has two columns: category `cat`, and score `ANT_tot`. The input is processed by `dplyr::count`, and yields an output table with two columns: score values `ANT_tot`, and number of occurrences of each value `n`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(cat = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
                  ANT_tot = c(45,72,51,51,51,45,30,31,30,31))
df2 <- df1 %>% count(ANT_tot)
df2

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ANT_tot     n
    <dbl> <int>
1      30     2
2      31     2
3      45     2
4      51     3
5      72     1
```

In the actual script, the user identifies a column to process by typing in a prefix, and that prefix is assigned to a char vec. In this example, I'll omit the console input step and just initialize the vector `score_name`.

```
score_name <- c('ANT')
```

This character string `ANT` is then used throughout the script by being pasted together with different suffixes to name various columns.

In other applications, I've succeeded by using `eval()` and `as.name()` to force R to treat the pasted-together string as a column name, e.g.,

```
eval(as.name(paste0(score_name, '_tot')))
```

In these other instances, the expression evaluates to the column name `ANT_tot` and R can process it as a variable.

However, it creates problematic output in the `dplyr::count` example I provided above:

```
df3 <- df1 %>% count(eval(as.name(paste0(score_name, '_tot'))))
df3

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  `eval(as.name(paste0(score_name, "_tot")))`     n
                                        <dbl> <int>
1                                          30     2
2                                          31     2
3                                          45     2
4                                          51     3
5                                          72     1
```

Rather than simply passing the pre-existing column name `ANT_tot`, it renames the column with the entire `eval()` expression, throwing a spanner in the works of downstream processing.

I'm stumped as to why this is happening, because the same expression produces expected results when used inside of other functions (e.g., `mean()`).

Perhaps its something idiosyncratic about the way evaluation works with `count()`? Or a problem with quotation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Look into NSE in `dplyr`, `rlang`, and Hadley's http://adv-r.had.co.nz/. My guess (I'm not proficient with it) is that you'll need the `!!` notation, perhaps `df1 %>% count(!!score_name)`.

Comment: See [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html). `count` and other `dplyr` functions quote their inputs, so you will need to carefully control how you evaluate the inputs. My approach when using both dplyr and base functions is to keep both character and quosure versions of supplied colnames around

Comment: with dplyr 0.6 and above `df3 <- df1 %>% count(!!as.name(paste0(score_name, '_tot')))` should work

Comment: Thanks to all for replying. Theo solution worked, and @r2evans and Calum_You pointed me in the right direction for background understanding.